# How to show parent categories on sub category pages Bigocmmerce Stencil

Tags: parent-child, bigcommerce

We have a client which wants the category pages set up in a specific way. They'll work as normal in Stencil, except that

http://5874stagingtwo.mybigcommerce.com/new-baby-shower/themes/themed-party-supplies/baby-brights/

would have the other categories scrolling at the top from this parent category

http://5874stagingtwo.mybigcommerce.com/new-baby-shower/themes/themed-party-supplies/

Is there a way I can do this in Stencil Cornerstone? I've looked through documentation and tried a few things but so far i've had no luck - including this

```
 {{#each category.parent.subcategories}}
        <div id="sub-cat-images">
            <a class="navList-action" href="{{url}}" alt="{{name}}" title="{{name}}"><img src="{{getImage image}}"></a>
            <div id="sub-cat-titles">
                <a class="navList-action" href="{{url}}" alt="{{name}}" title="{{name}}">{{name}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have tried?

Comment: Hi, I've updated, thanks!